# Redirect if using trailing slash in URL. htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, trailing-slash

How can I make it so when a user uses a trailing slash, for example this link:

```
website.com/staff/
```

It will redirect to a 404 not found page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /$ - [R=404,L]
```

This will return a 404 not found error for all requests (except directories) if they contain a trailing slash.